# Error : Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-mfannvv4rp-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS and decided to do some projects by following guides. I decided to create a word press website external to Amazon RDS database to Elastic Beanstalk. I'm stuck in the app deployment phase when we deploy the source bundle in the environment. After a couple of minutes after deployment I get this error:
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-mfannvv4rp-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: null. This starts a series of errors until the initial configurations are back. This 'null' is throwing me off as I don't know where the problem comes from.
Screen provided.

I tried playing with IAM roles and added AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleRDS but it didn't work.

Comment: Look in the cloudwatch console for the failed resource. It should show a failure reason there.

Comment: Where exactly please in the cloudwatch console ? I have 0 in everything

Comment: Click on the relevant stack then click the resources tag.

Comment: Okay this is what I can see https://www.kapwing.com/videos/64d7cd196b0a3b0217be3101 , and all the 9 resources I found were checked green, do I screenshot them for you?